# Why is my union of two queries not ordering correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

```
 (SELECT `size`, `type` FROM `table` WHERE `type`='a' ORDER BY `size` ASC)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT `size`,`type` FROM `table` WHERE `type`='b' ORDER BY `size` DESC)
```

Why isn't this query working as I hope? It separates the result array into types 'a' and then types 'b', but within the type 'a' results, they are not ordered by size (size is a positive bigint).

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: while within the type 'b' results they are ordered by size?

Comment: @OfirBaruch no they are not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The results of a query are not ordered, unless you use an `order by` clause (or in MySQL a `group by` clause).  Try this to get what you want:

```
(SELECT `size`, `type` FROM `table` WHERE `type`='a')
UNION ALL 
(SELECT `size`,`type` FROM `table` WHERE `type`='b')
order by type,
         (case when `type` = 'a' then size end) asc,
         (case when `type` = 'b' then size end) desc;
```

Ordering clauses on subqueries are generally ignored (the exception is when you have `limit`).  And, even when not ignored may have not effect on the outer query.

Actually, forget the `union all` entirely:

```
select size, `type`
from table
where type in ('a', 'b')
order by type,
         (case when `type` = 'a' then size end) asc,
         (case when `type` = 'b' then size end) desc;
```

The first `type` in the `order by` clause is unnecessary, but I do think that it makes the intention of the ordering clearer.

Comment: backticks need to be changed to quotes in `case when type = 'a'...`

Comment: Thanks. I tried your query which omits the union all and it worked nicely. I forgot to add one detail, I need 15 of type a and 15 of type b, is that still possible with your second neater query or do I need to perform a union all like in your first suggestion? I may only have 5 of type a but 100 of type b...

Comment: @user1796995 . . . If you have a `limit` for each value, then it is easiest to use the `union all` version that you started with (moving the `order by` outside the union, of course).